# How to activate a window?

Tags: cocoa

Though I searched and tried a lot, I can not make a second window activated.

The code I used to display another window while main window is activating:

```
preferencesWindowController = (PreferencesWindowController*)[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"Preferences"];
[preferencesWindowController showWindow: preferencesWindowController];
[[preferencesWindowController window] orderFrontRegardless];
[[preferencesWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront: preferencesWindowController];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

---

After trying debugger, I see that [preferencesWindowController window] is nil

```
preferencesWindowController = (PreferencesWindowController*)[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"Preferences"];
[preferencesWindowController showWindow: self];
NSWindow* window = [preferencesWindowController window]; //---> nil
```

Why is it nil?

---

The nib file contains Window and PreferencesWindowController.

---

Sorry, I use multi nib wrong. I follow this example and have it works: http://maestric.com/doc/mac/cocoa/multiple_nibs . Instead of adding a window controller to nib, setting file's owner class to window controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
preferencesWindowController = (PreferencesWindowController*)[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"Preferences"];
```

Casting the result to PreferencesWindowController isn't going to change the type of the object which was created. You need to create the right kind of object:

```
preferencesWindowController = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"Preferences"];
```

Also, ensure that you've actually connected the window outlet from File's Owner to the window in your nib.

Comment: The nib file contains Window and PreferencesWindowController.
Your code doesn't help, the preferencesWindowController object is filled with zero after initialization.

Comment: Did you read the second part of Jim's answer? Have you connected the window outlet from File's Owner to your window in your nib?

Comment: "Also, ensure that you've actually connected the window outlet from File's Owner to the window in your nib." In my .xib I see a 'File's Owner'. In the connection inspector I can select the 'New Referencing Outlet' to the window. Is that what you mean? Why it is needed? Once I made a persistent reference to the window the problem was solved, regardless of this.